# Determining how much time has passed since the app was used

Tags: objective-c

I am looking to make an app that, after a given time of no use, will close or give a message to the user.

How can I implement this?

Comment: What’s your target platform: Mac OS X, iOS, or some other platform?

Comment: ios , i didn't try anything because i really don't know how to start

Comment: What do you want us to do for you, then? We are happy to answer specific questions about difficulties you're facing, but this site is not here to simply provide code. If you're looking for tutorials, a search of this site or Google will turn up plenty of links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
[NSApp performSelector:@selector(terminate:) 
  withObject:nil 
  afterDelay:[your delay...]];
```

Answer (score 1):

[UKIDleTimer](http://zathras.de/programming/cocoa/UKIdleTimer.zip/UKIdleTimer/) is what you're looking for. You create a timer that only fires when the system becomes idle and implement the following method in its delegate:

```
-(void) timerBeginsIdling: (id)sender {
    // terminate app
    [NSApp terminate];
}
```

Comment: I think that won't work on iPhone. It's Carbon... Do not know for a fact tho.

Answer (score 0):

Look at various Hello World examples on the net for Objective C. Once you have a hello world example going, you'll want to add some event listeners to monitor user activity. When any of those event handlers are called as a result of a users' actions, they should set a variable with the time of that action. Finally, set up a timer to check for user inactivity, say once every 30 seconds, which checks that value, to see if it's exceeded the time at which you want the application to close. If so, then send an exit command.